# How do I request further information on an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I have asked a question and received a good response. But I want more information about it. How am I supposed to go about asking it? Just a create a new question?

Answer (score 12):

You can reply to comments, that's a good start.

You can also edit your original question asking for clarification.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh, duh.  I didn't even see that button :-/

Comment: It takes some time until the button appears, you need a reputation of 50.

Answer (score 4):

You could always add a comment to the answer asking for more information.

Comment: How do we know if anyone has commented on the comment?  Is there a notification system in place?

Comment: On your profile page, there is a "responses" tab.

Answer (score 4):

I think modifying the original question after there are already many answer can lead to very confusing threads; it can make the highest voted answer either inaccurate or so it answers only a piece of the new question. I think the best way is to either comment on the answer that you want more information on or if what you want more information on is detailed enough, asking a new question that references the first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/189165) to attract more users to your question or to request better quality answers.

Digging a six year old question from the grave! :] I don't know when bounties were introduced to the Stack Exchange network, but I'm pretty sure that it was *after* this question and all of its answers were made.  So this answer is a little bit of an update.

Answer (score -1):

Also, there are tags called "needs-more-answers" and "needs-answer"

Comment: No, there isn't. These are meta-tags and are long gone.